# Sudden change in the plot format

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, graph

About more than a month ago, I realized the plots I was getting from my code have a different format altogether (background not white anymore, grid added, fonts changed, legend affected). I looked and could not find any changes that could have affected the default format of my plots.

Does anyone know if this is a change they made to matplotlib (3.1.1)? Also, is there a way to fix this (preferably without having to define every characteristic of the plot all over)?

[image: Previous look, what I want]

[image: Current look, how it looks like now]

Comment: 2nd one looks like it's using seaborn.

Comment: Matplotlib did not change its default style in recent versions. Your second plot uses a different style. This style is either set via code (e.g. `plt.style.use(..)`, or `seaborn.set()` or similar), or you have replaced your [matplotlibrc file](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html).

Comment: Agreed, the 2nd plot looks like it uses the 'ggplot' style.

Comment: Thank you all! You were right about **seaborn**. Someone else had added`plt.style.use('seaborn')` and I had not realized. Commenting this line changed everything back to normal.